# Detect JSF session timeout/refresh/back/forward and return to login screen

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 1.2 application that has a session going on and whenever the session timeouts or the user presses the browse back or refresh page, the session gets messed up and things start to behave unexpectedly.

I would like to simply bring the user back to a predefined login screen whenever that happens.
Authentication is handled inside the JSF application.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using  [PhaseListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html)

Example:

MyPhaseListener.java

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
      //If you have a login, so you have a user in session. Try to retrieve this value
      //and it will return null if the user is not logged in or theres no more session
      //and...

      if (null == FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("myUserInSession") {

         //Redirect to login using mapped navigation configs in faces-config.xml
         try {
             NavigationHandler nh = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
             nh.handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "stringToReturnLogin");
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }

         //OR using redirect      
         try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://localhost:xxxx/App_Context/Page.xhtml");
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }
      }
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }
}
```

Configuring the listener in faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config version="1.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

(...)

   <lifecycle>
      <phase-listener>yourPackage.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
   </lifecycle>

(...)

</faces-config>
```

Yes, you dont need to put ".java".

Comment: does this take care of the user pressing the back or refresh button?

Comment: I don't know, try it.. My app is full ajax, so it does not generate historic and the browser back button is always disabled. I blocked F5 and context menu (made my own context menu using richfaces).

Comment: PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW. It returns RESTORE_VIEW for all the phases if you override this method like this. I think It should be PhaseId.ANY_PHASE.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!! I'll try it after the weekend and let know I it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but here goes anyway.
You probably want to put the following in your web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/sales/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

That will redirect the ViewExpiredException. I guess that will hold for any other exceptions that come up.